# Return in Javascript with multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, function, return, parseint

```
function parseInteger(value){
    "use strict";
    return parseInteger(value, 10);
}
```

The function recieves one parameter, but it returns: `return parseInteger(value, 10)`
What does this mean?

Comment: maybe it's a function in your javascript code.

Comment: This means you have some infinite recursion. Isn't that second function supposed to be `parseInt`? I that case, the `10` would be the radix. (Which means it should try to parse the `value` as a decimal number)

Answer (score 1):

This means you have some infinite recursion: `parseInteger` will call `parseInteger`, which will call `parseInteger` and so on.

I'm assuming that second function is actually supposed to be [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

I that case, the `10` would be the radix, which means it will try to parse the `value` as a decimal number.
It also seems `parseInteger` is just a wrapper for `parseInt` to make sure you always parse your value as a decimal number.